# URLs restricted by robots.txt errors on google search console

Tags: google-search-console

i am creating a wordpress site on subdomain and I am facing this error:
Sitemap contains urls which are blocked by robots.txt. on google search console

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 0):

The `robots.txt` file regulates web robots (typically search engine robots) how to crawl pages on their website, So if a link is blocked by `robots.txt` then you should go to that file and edit it and remove the link from `Disallow` or add it to the `Allow`.

> **For Example**

`user-agent : *`

`Disallow : /wp-admin/` **>>** This will block the web crawler to crawl the `/wp-admin/`

`Allow : /wp-content/` **>>** This will Allow the web crawler to crawl the `/wp-content/`

Here `user-agent` can be anyone i.e. **a user** or **a web crawler**.

> See this and try configure the your `robots.txt` [on Moz.com](https://moz.com/learn/seo/robotstxt)